# chrome does not save my passwords

Tags: debian, password, chrome

When I had to login in a site, Chrome used to offer me a number of possible user names and later the password associated with the user I choose (provided that I saved the user-password association previously).

Now Chrome still offers the correct possible users but then offers no password, I have to enter the password (if I remember it, that is, otherwise it's password resetting) and, after a successful login, Chrome ask for permission to save the password.  I give permission, of course, but next time I login it's again no password remembered.

If I open the `Settings->Passwords` screen I see (the equivalent of)

```
Offer to save passwords [YES]
Auto Sign-in            [YES]
```

and below

```
Saved Passwords
    Saved passwords will appear here
```

that is, no password is really saved.

Final consideration, the same page permits to `View and manage saved passwords in your Google Account` and if I go there I can see all my sites, my users and my passwords except, important exception! that some of these passwords are stale.

I'm on Debian Sid, Chrome is `Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
 from Google's official `.deb`

What can I do to fix this annoying problem?

#### UPDATE

This is what I get when I launch Chrome from the shell

```
$ google-chrome
[18891:18891:0906/221132.855189:ERROR:sandbox_linux.cc(369)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[18856:18990:0906/221136.514201:ERROR:object_proxy.cc(619)] Failed to call method: org.freedesktop.Notifications.GetCapabilities: object_path= /org/freedesktop/Notifications: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Notifications was not provided by any .service files
[18891:18891:0906/221143.906640:ERROR:buffer_manager.cc(488)] [.DisplayCompositor]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glBufferData: <- error from previous GL command
[18856:18996:0906/221151.512723:ERROR:password_syncable_service.cc(191)] Passwords datatype error was encountered: Failed to get passwords from store.
```

In particular, `Passwords datatype error was encountered: Failed to get passwords from store.` seems relevant wrt my issues.

Comment: maybe ur chrome cache is full. try to clear/increase it...

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761800/chromium-saved-passwords-are-not-loaded-until-save-a-password, https://superuser.com/questions/573602/chrome-not-saving-passwords-and-not-auto-filling-existing-login-passwords

Comment: @JL2210 The related questions: askubuntu one, I don't use a keyring, everything worked nicely until some time ago; superuser one, the accepted answer can be superposed with what I have described in my question.  I'll see later all the remaining answers.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: make sure that you're syncing the data to/from the google account within your chrome browser.  It might be worth checking that and also including pastbin link to more logs.

Comment: I guess that is not what you want to hear and not the solution to your question, but it is recommended in general to use a separate password store: https://www.maketecheasier.com/are-browser-password-manager-good-enough/

Answer (score 30):

Sometimes a couple of login files get corrupt, and stop google-chrome from saving the passwords.

To fix it, close google-chrome.  Terminal to the following directory and remove the two files, Login Data and Login Data-journal.

```
cd ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
rm 'Login Data'
rm 'Login Data-journal'
```

Now open Chrome and URL to 'Chrome://settings/passwords' and see if the passwords have returned under 'Saved Passwords...'.  Try saving a password and check the above password URL to see if it is now being saved.

Comment: If you have installed Chromium via Snap, the solution is the same except that you need to substitute the directory `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default` for the directory in the first line.

Comment: Wow, that worked. Thanks!
A note that that only fixes the default profile. You need to do the same in the `Profile 1`, `Profile 2`, etc folders next to the `Default folder`. Also I noticed that some of those folders also had a `Login Data 2-journal` folder. Not sure if those needed to be deleted too, but I deleted them too. Now all my profiles offer my saved passwords!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue "Saved Passwords" "Saved passwords will appear here" was empty while my usernames and passwords were saved properly and worked. I was playing a bit with great Python script https://rtfm.co.ua/en/chromium-linux-keyrings-secret-service-passwords-encryption-and-store/ and found that by removing password (database rows) that can't be decoded by my master password I got the "Saved Passwords" list back.

To be more technical. I created backup of may "~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Login Data" (Fedora 33) Chrome config (sqlite3 database). Exported my original "logins" table (e.g. by "sqlitebrowser" tool), used editor to remove rows/passwords that can't be properly decoded (all from IDs 1 to 57) and used `~/.config/google-chrome/Default $ sqlite3 Login\ Data 'delete from logins' && sqlite3 Login\ Data ".read /home/mj//logins-ok.sql" && google-chrome` to check that it works.

That took me a few hours of debugging a few hundreds of my logins/passwords are back. I tried to report it as new Chrome bug. IMO it is caused by some decode crash, or not valid utf8 results of the decode going to the search/sorting operation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Ubuntu 20.04. I fixed the issue by renaming the existing google chrome profile. Below are the steps of it.

1. Login into your account through ssh.
2. `cd ~/.config`
3. Rename the existing google chrome profile.

   ```
   mv google-chrome google-chrome-old
   ```
4. Start google chrome browser.
5. Sign in with your account again and sync it.